# How to redirect when having multiple indexes view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have multiple index views for different users, but they share the same Create/Edit/Details/Delete views. So, when editing a user with the role customer in the Edit view, I want to redirect the admin to the Index of Customers only.

I don't thinks tag helpers can have multiple values, so I don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure the application in Startup.cs add "RolePolicy" by adding a line of services

> services.AddAuthorization

in startup.cs

```
//more preferences..
private bool AuthorizeAccess(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        return context.User.IsInRole("Admin") &&
                context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "Edit Role" && claim.Value == "true") ||
                context.User.IsInRole("Super Admin");
    }
//AddAuthorization..
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {options.AddPolicy("DeleteRolePolicy",
                policy => policy.RequireClaim("Delete Role", "true"));
            options.AddPolicy("CreateRolePolicy",
                policy => policy.RequireClaim("Create Role", "true"));
            options.AddPolicy("EditRolePolicy",
                policy => policy.RequireClaim("Edit Role" , "true"));  
//For more preferences you can use 
 options.AddPolicy("EditRolePolicy",
                 policy => policy.RequireAssertion(context =>AuthorizeAccess(context)));

});
```

in controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Authorize(Policy = "EditRolePolicy")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EditViewModel model)
    {
       .....

           return View(model);
     }
```

Also, the exception can be added in .cshtml But it is preferable, in security terms, to be inside controller , Because the data may be accessed using the link directly.
in .cshtml

```
 @inject IAuthorizationService authorizationService

<h1>Roles</h1>

@if ((await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "EditRolePolicy")).Succeeded)
   {

<a asp-controller="Ucontroller" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@role.Id" class="btn btn-primary">  Edit </a>

   }
```

Final in _ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

@addTagHelper *,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

To expand the roles, you can visit this link
[Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

If you divide the powers of the pipeline and add the correct services, you will be able to add the exceptions that distinguish each individual customer safely.
*I hope I could help.*

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply, much appreciated!!